# Visualforce Email Template Vertical Spacing issue

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I have the following line of code for EmailTemplate. When sending the email I am attaching the articles in the emailTemplate. The issue is between the email text and the Article there is a huge white space. I need some help on how I can remove the white space.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Thank you for contacting xyz, RE: {!relatedTo.CaseNumber}" recipientType="Contact"
    relatedToType="Case">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
        <div contenteditable="true">
            <apex:outputText value="Dear {!relatedTo.Contact.Name}," /> <br /><br />
            <apex:outputText value="Thank you for contacting the xyz company regarding {!relatedTo.Subject}" />
            <br /><br />
            <apex:outputText value="The reference number for your call today is {!relatedTo.CaseNumber}" /><br /><br />
            <apex:outputText value="The information below is being provided to address your request." /><br /><br />
            <c:EmailTemplateVFCtrl KbId="{!relatedTo.Id}" /><br /><br />
        </div>
        <apex:outputText
            value="DISCLAIMER: All policy information contained in this knowledge base article is based upon the referenced xyz policy document." />
        <br /><br />
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

**EmailTemplateVFCtrl**

```
<apex:component controller="EmailTemplateCls" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="KbId" type="Id" description="Assigning case ID to Controller" assignTo="{!ServiceReqId}"/>
    <table style="border: none; margin : 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;">
        <apex:repeat value="{!kavData}" var="kb">
            <p align="justify">
                <tr>
                    <td valign ="top" style="border: none;"><b><apex:outputText value="{!kb.Title}" escape="false"/></b></td>
                </tr>            
                <tr>
                    <div style="page-break-after:always;">
                        <td valign ="top" style="border: none;"><apex:outputText value="{!kb.Answer__c}" escape="false"/></td><br/>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </p>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:component>
```

**EmailTemplateCls**: I am just pulling all the attached articles for that Case.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the EmailTemplateVFCtrl component code as well.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCheng for pointing out the VF page. I updated the question.

Comment: if you inspect the HTML for the generated email, you'll probably see that the actual article has its own embedded HTML that causes the additional spacing